# Joomla 1.7 - can't find Meta Titles

Tags: joomla, seo, joomla1.7

we moved a site for a client a while back that someone else created. Its running on Joomla 1.7.

We want to do some light SEO work for them but I can't for the life of me find the Meta/SEO title field anywhere.

All the support posts I've looked at say its here or there but for me its not. It seems to be know where! In the meta options section when editing an artcile there is a description and keyword field but no title.

Some help would be appreciated. This client can't justify a new website.

Thanks!

---

Update:
we ended up upgrading this install to 2.5, still couldn't edit the meta titles anywhere. So I installed a plugin which gave me the title field but it had no effect! Can only assume the theme hasn't been put together properly. The conclusion is that its now quicker for us to just move them to WordPress where stuff works properly! :)

Comment: For the site title? Look in global configuration.  For specific content items there are a lot of places where you can override the title field to get a different metadata field. For example the page title field when you make a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working more with Wordpress than Joomla, but I think that you should download an extension if you want to have a meta-title in the pages. For the home page you can change it from `Menu - Main menu - Home`.

Comment: We work with WordPress usually too!! Thanks - will take a look in the menu section.